# JWT with RSA public and private key

Tags: security, jwt, rsa

I don't understand why I should use the public key in signing JWT. The private key is there so that the JWT token cannot be forged, yes? But why additionally sign it with a public key? Are there any benefits? Because I don't understand it at all. After all, a JWT signed with a private key can be read without the public key. What is this public key for?

Comment: The private key is for signing, the public for verification. *But why additionally sign it with a public key?* - never heard this, where did you get this from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT Private / Public Key Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538047/jwt-private-public-key-confusion)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But now I have question - if API which authentication is based on Bearer token then it should have public key for verification, yes? But any API will has own public key, or public key will be one for any API?

Comment: You verify the token with the public key of the server that issued the token. The API needs to get the server's public key (very often it will call the server's jwks endpoint) and then it can verify the JWT. It doesn't need its own public key to verify the server's token.

Comment: Thanks, I had a problem with that. I think the topic can be ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signing a JWT means you take the cleartext, signing it with a key - either the private key from an RSA pair or a symmetric key, then add the signature to the JWT.  The JWT itself is still readable without decrtypting the signature.  But someone with the key can decrypt the signature and confirm the contents match the cleartext.

The advantage of using RSA over symmetric key is that anyone can verify the signature without them having to have a secret key.  You can either pass the public key to the JWT recipient over a side channel, or if using OAuth2 it provides a URL to access public keys.

You would use the public key for encrypting, not signing.  You encrypt with the recipient's public key so that only the recipient can decrypt it.

Comment: Ok, you would use a public key to encrypt, not sign.