# RSA 256 jwt verify method throws JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature

Tags: node.js, jwt, rsa, nest, express-jwt

I'm working on server to server authentication and I want to access one request from serverB.
So that I have created 2 RSA key file in serverA repo.

1.safety-private.key

2.safety-public.key

And I'm sending request to serverB by following code.

ServerA :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const fs = require("fs");

@Injectable()
export class RsaTokenAuthService {
  loadKey(path) {
    if (!path) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      return fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  exportRSAKey() {
    return this.loadKey(process.env.JWT_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY);
  }

  getSigningConfig(subject) {
    const rsaSignOptions = {
      algorithm: 'RS256',
      expiresIn: 15 * 60, // expires in 15min
      issuer: process.env.ISSUER,
      audience: `${process.env.FORM_API_URL}`,
    };

    if (this.exportRSAKey()) {
      return {
        options: { ...rsaSignOptions, subject },
        secret: this.exportRSAKey(),
      };
    }
  }

  buildToken(subject, payload = {}) {
    const sign = this.getSigningConfig(subject);
    return jwt.sign(payload, sign.secret, sign.options);
  }
}
```

ServerB:
Again I have created two RSA files in serverB repo

1. serverB-private.key
2. serverB-public.key

When I run both the server on localhost and having different port and try to verify the token it throws the invalid token error.
Here is my verification code on serverB.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");


const rsaVerifyOptions = {
  // only allow RSA + SHA256
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
}

function loadKey(path) {
  if (!path) {
    return null;
  }
  try {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function exportRSAKey() {
  return loadKey(process.env.JWT_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY);
}

function getVerifyConfig(subject) {
  if (exportRSAKey()) {
    return {
      options: rsaVerifyOptions,
      secret: exportRSAKey(),
    };
  }
}


function verifyToken(token) {
  const { options, secret } = getVerifyConfig();
  try {
    return jwt.verify(token, secret, options);
  } catch (err) {
    // in prod, don't use console.log because it is synchronous
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  }
}

function decodeAndVerify(req, res, next) {
  // Authorization: Bearer <jwt-token>

  // 1. extract Authrorization header
  const authorizationHeader = req.get("Authorization");

  if (!authorizationHeader) {
    return res.status(401).json("missing token");
  }

  // 2. extract the JWT
  // "Bearer: my-jwt-token"
  const token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);

  // 3. decode token
  const decodedToken = verifyToken(token);

  if (!decodedToken) {
    return res.status(401).json("invalid token");
  }
  req.token = decodedToken;
  next();
}

module.exports = {
  verifyToken,
  decodeAndVerify
}
```

Please help me. Am I doing wrong somewhere ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You mention two key pairs. Are these two different pairs or is it just one pair copied to both servers?

Comment: two different pairs

Comment: What are you doing with two different pairs? You can verify a signature that was created with private key A only with the public key A. What's the role of the second pair?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT Private / Public Key Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538047/jwt-private-public-key-confusion)

Comment: If the linked q/a helped, please click on "yes, it answers my question" to confirm.